# SQL Server - Cursor and Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, cursors

this query is working but not giving me the output I want.

I am expecting to have 'FAILED' when one of the two conditions is met at least one time through the rows in the columns [TVF] or [RPPS]. But here I have always 'OK' as output in my updated table. Normally, I should have 'FAILED' for the row [AFUP] and 'OK' for the row [BICHATP].

Can you run it on your machine?

```
drop table [MyTable]
drop table [BICHATP]
drop table [AFUP]


CREATE TABLE [AFUP]
(
    [TVF] nvarchar(10),
    [RPPS] nvarchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE [BICHATP]
(
    [TVF] nvarchar(10),
    [RPPS] nvarchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO [AFUP] ([TVF], [RPPS]) VALUES
    ('M006', '1010'), ('M054','1000'), ('M015', '2324');

INSERT INTO [BICHATP] ([TVF], [RPPS]) VALUES
    ('M000', '1101'), ('M090','1001'), ('M012', '1023');

CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [Tabs] nvarchar(100),
    [Check_column] nvarchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Tabs]) VALUES
    ('AFUP'), ('BICHATP');


DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Tabs nvarchar(10);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Tabs] FROM [MyTable];

OPEN cur1;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @Tabs
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = 'update [MyTable]
                set [Check_column] = 
                    case when left([TVF],4) = ''M006'' or left([RPPS],4) = ''1009'' then ''FAILED''
                         else ''OK''
                    end
               from DB_SANOFI.dbo.' + @Tabs;

    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @Tabs
END

CLOSE cur1;
DEALLOCATE cur1;

select *
from MyTable
```

Tables

```
    AFUP           BICHATP
------------     ------------
M006 | 1010      M000 | 1101
M054 | 1000      M090 | 1001
M015 | 2324      M012 | 1023
```

Expected result:

```
Tabs    | Check column
-----------------------
   UFAP | FAIL
BICHATP | OK
```

Comment: The `UPDATE` statement has no `WHERE` clause so both rows are updated each iteration. Also, the source has 3 rows so the results are not deterministic. I think you want a `WHERE` clause so that only one row is updated each iteration and an `EXISTS` subquery in the `CASE` expression. Add expected results to your question for clarification.

Comment: I updated the questions according to your remarks.
What do you mean by "not deterministic"?

Comment: By not deterministic I mean results will be random because of the multiple rows in the FROM clause. `EXISTS` (or `NOT EXISTS`) correlated with a `WHERE` clause ensures consistent results for each execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you want `OK` in the `MyTable` if you cannot find **any** row on the *joined* tables that meets your *FAILED* conditions.  I'm using `NOT EXISTS` and also made sure I'm only updating `MyTable` for the specific table being *processed*.

Let me know if I have misunderstood your requirements.

```
drop table if exists [MyTable]
drop table if exists [BICHATP]
drop table if exists [AFUP]


CREATE TABLE [AFUP]
(
    [TVF] nvarchar(10),
    [RPPS] nvarchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE [BICHATP]
(
    [TVF] nvarchar(10),
    [RPPS] nvarchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO [AFUP] ([TVF], [RPPS]) VALUES
    ('M006', '1010'), ('M054','1000'), ('M015', '2324');

INSERT INTO [BICHATP] ([TVF], [RPPS]) VALUES
    ('M000', '1101'), ('M090','1001'), ('M012', '1023');

CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [Tabs] nvarchar(100),
    [Check_column] nvarchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Tabs]) VALUES
    ('AFUP'), ('BICHATP');


DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Tabs nvarchar(10);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Tabs] FROM [MyTable];

OPEN cur1;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @Tabs
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = 'update [MyTable]
                set [Check_column] = case when NOT EXISTS
                    (SELECT * FROM ' + @Tabs + ' where
                    left([TVF],4) = ''M006'' or left([RPPS],4) = ''1009'')
                    then ''OK''
                         else ''FAILED''
                    end
               from ' + @Tabs + ' WHERE [MyTable].Tabs = ''' + @Tabs + '''';

               print @cmd
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @Tabs
END

CLOSE cur1;
DEALLOCATE cur1;

select *
from MyTable
```

---

```
| Tabs    | Check_column |
|---------|--------------|
| AFUP    | FAILED       |
| BICHATP | OK           |
```